# Apache Camel split is failing with Objects

Tags: java, apache-camel

List of String could be split but List of Objects split is failing.Values are not getting printed.Please help me to find the issue.f2 is never getting printed only f1 is coming.

**Output:**

```
s1
s2
f1
s1
s2
f1
```

**Code:**

```
public class SampleTimerRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("timer:simpleTimer1?period=2000").process((exchange) -> {
            List<TestPOJO> names = new ArrayList<>();
            names.add(new TestPOJO("f1"));
            names.add(new TestPOJO("f2"));
            exchange.getOut().setBody(names);
        }).split(body(TestPOJO.class)).to("stream:out");


        from("timer:simpleTimer2?period=2000").process((exchange) -> {
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
            names.add("s1");
            names.add("s2");
            exchange.getOut().setBody(names);
        }).split(body(String.class)).to("stream:out");

    }
}

class TestPOJO {
    private String fName;

    public TestPOJO(String f) {
        fName = f;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Down voter please give your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your route to

```
 from("timer:simpleTimer1?period=2000").process((exchange) -> {
            List<TestPOJO> names = new ArrayList<>();
            names.add(new TestPOJO("f1"));
            names.add(new TestPOJO("f2"));
            exchange.getOut().setBody(names);
        }).split(simple("${body}")).to("stream:out");
```

And also make you TestPOJO public

Comment: Plus with Acceptance , Thanks for your answer!